# Ajax put to add XML entries into XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, http

I am trying to add some emails taken from an inputbox into a .txt file present on my webserver. Here is the code :

```
email = document.getElementById("mail").value;

$.ajax({
  url: 'maillist.txt',
  datatype: 'text',
  type: 'PUT',
  data: email + '; ',
 success: function(data) {
    alert('Should have work yay!');
  }
});
```

but that doesn't work on any browser. :(

I have tried using javascript classic methods but it was a no go as well...

I would need either a PUT or POST method, either jQuery or JS, to be able to do this on internet explorer 8 and up as well as firefox and chrome. Emails should appear in the text file as

email1@cooldomain.com; email2@cooldomain.com; .....

Just so it works with our in-house VBA Macro. :)

Also, could there be a method for dropping data into XML files (aka create a new XML entry with form data)? And also, is it possible to upload a file from client side to server side using jQuery? Because i would need users to fill up forms and drop their data into an XML file, and link up a file they choose with that. That way they could add stuff into the XML themselves and they would show up brand new into the webpage.

Kindoff "reddit" or "4chan" like if you know the references.

Thanks for your time, really appreciated!

Comment: The code you have should make the PUT request without any problems. Is your server set up to process it?

Comment: What do you mean my server is set to process it? I use XAMPP and i have no tweaked anything. Would it work as default? If not, how do i set it up? And if i merge this whole thing into a real webserver, will it work or will we need to change the webserver policies? I am pretty lost into this whole webserver thing, i lack experience :/ But still, thanks for the comment man, really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can't post from a browser to a text file on the server side. You need to have some sort of code on the server side that will receive the HTTP PUT, and persist the data to a file local to the server.

Comment: Could you elaborate or point out some more in depth readings about those "sort of codes on the server side that will receive the HTTP PUT"? Because all i want to do is drop a string of text into a text file, nothing more... :/

Comment: Just search around for AJAX code samples. They usually have a server side component/page in Ruby/PHP/C#/JavaScript etc. What you're looking for is a client-side solution, which may or may not be available. Search for "writing to local file from JavaScript".